# base type is not CLS-compliant in Third Party Control

Tags: c#, .net, cls-compliant

I have a control that I purchased.  When I tried to inherit from the control I get this message:

```
Warning: 'MyNamespace.MyFile': base type 'Mooseworks.UI.MwTextBox' is not CLS-compliant
```

Is there any way around this besides asking the vendor of my control to make their control CLS compliant?

Comment: Follow this link, you'll find the answer http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Making-Your-Code-CLS-Compliant/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to the build tab of the project and added 3009 in the "Suppress warnings:" section.

As this is not my code I don't feel too bad about suppressing this warning.

Comment: Yes but you should feel bad for using such code :-) Just kidding

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - I agree... But there are so few .netcf mask edit controls out there.  You can't be too picky unless you want to roll your own.  :)

Comment: You could also suppress the warning only for the classes you need (not for the project) using: #pragma warning disable 3009